ImageTk module fails
I'm trying to use the pillow package for Python in my Visual Studio Code IDE
But it seems like the ImageTk module is not working properly.
Every time I run the script it tells me that there is an error around that line.
enter image description here
I tried to correct the text, uninstalling and installing Pillow back again. By the time I installed pillow, and updated it, a message appeared. I don{t know if that has something to be with my issue.
This is the message:
enter image description here

What if you upgrade to Python 3.12.5 or Python 3.14.0?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
